# Moving all rows to a set of new columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I want to move the second row of my data frame to be the first elements of a new set of columns.

I have a data frame,

```
**Topics**                                      **co-authors**
Object Detection; Deep Learning; IOU            Bandala, Argel A.
Character Recognition; Tesseract; Number        Vicerra, Ryan Rhay P.
Robot; End Effectors; Malus                     Concepcion, Ronnie
Crops; Plant Diseases and Disorders; Beriberi   Sybingco, E.
Swarm Robotics; Swarm; Social Insects           Billones, Robert Kerwin C.
```

and I want a new data frame to have columns as follows,

| Topic_1 | Topic_2 | Topic_3 | Topic_4 | Topic_5 | Coauthor_1 | Coauthor_2  | Coauthor_3  | Coauthor_4  | Coauthor_5 |

How do I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example is ambiguous, please provide a smaller example but ensure that the output is matching the input.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous, but assuming you want to perform one-hot encoding on the two columns:

```
out = (df['Topics'].str.get_dummies(sep='; ')
       .join(df['co-authors'].str.get_dummies(sep='; '))
       )
```

Output:

```
   Beriberi  Character Recognition  Crops  Deep Learning  End Effectors  IOU  Malus  Number  Object Detection  Plant Diseases and Disorders  Robot  Social Insects  Swarm  Swarm Robotics  Tesseract  Bandala, Argel A.  Billones, Robert Kerwin C.  Concepcion, Ronnie  Sybingco, E.  Vicerra, Ryan Rhay P.
0         0                      0      0              1              0    1      0       0                 1                             0      0               0      0               0          0                  1                           0                   0             0                      0
1         0                      1      0              0              0    0      0       1                 0                             0      0               0      0               0          1                  0                           0                   0             0                      1
2         0                      0      0              0              1    0      1       0                 0                             0      1               0      0               0          0                  0                           0                   1             0                      0
3         1                      0      1              0              0    0      0       0                 0                             1      0               0      0               0          0                  0                           0                   0             1                      0
4         0                      0      0              0              0    0      0       0                 0                             0      0               1      1               1          0                  0                           1                   0             0                      0
```